# How to pass parameters to Web Start Javafx Application

Tags: java, jsp, javafx-8, java-web-start

I have .html file as follows which calls .jsp:

```
<html> 

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>


<FORM method="post" ACTION="http://localhost/science_city_video_1/Science_City_2.jsp" name="search_push">
            <input type="hidden" name="video" value="Science_City_Video_1"> 

<input type="hidden" name="video_description" value="This is the First Video of Science City Cross Roads">  

                   <A href="javascript:document.search_push.submit()" class="style18"  >
                    This is our First Video of Science City Cross Roads

                    </A>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

The jsp file is as follows which when clicked should start Web Start Javafx Application:

```
    <html><head>


<script>


    function launchApp() {
        dtjava.launch(
            {   url: 'Science_City.jnlp'
                params: {
                           video: "<%=request.getParameter("video")%>",
                           video_description: "<%=request.getParameter("video_description")%>"
                }
            },
            {   javafx : '2.2+'  },
            {}
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>

<a href="Science_City.jnlp" onclick="launchApp(); return false;">
    Launch me!
</a>

<body>



    </body></html>
```

Now two things are happening:

1) When web start is launched the parameters obtained from html file do not appear and i get null value in javafx application.

2) I tried hardcoding parameter values in jnlp file but it gives me null when called from Javafx Application using method getParameters().getNamed();

The .jnlp file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://localhost/science_city_video_1/" href="Science_City.jnlp">
    <information>
    <title>Science City Video</title>
    <vendor>Jahnvi Consultants</vendor>
    <description>null</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>




  <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Science_City.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>



 <application-desc name="Sample app"
        mainClass="java_video_in_browser.VideoPlayer">
    <!-- parameter with name 'simpleParam' and fixed string value-->
    <param name="video" value="Science_City_1"/>
    <!-- parameter with name 'complexParam' with value generated 
         at build time -->

 </application-desc> 


 <!--  
 <param name="video" value="Science_City_1"/>
 <param name="video_description" value="Robert"/>






 <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="java_video_in_browser.VideoPlayer"  name="VideoPlayer" />
   -->


</jnlp>
```

Comment: The .jsp file is obtained from web start javafx tutorial on oracle website. .jnlp file works fine for my other applications.Also i have successfully passed parameters for web based javafx application when i embed javafx into the browswer.

Comment: Still waiting for somebody to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is partial answer to my question. If the .jnlp file is edited like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://localhost/science_city_video_1/" href="Science_City.jnlp">
        <information>
        <title>Science City Video</title>
        <vendor>Jahnvi Consultants</vendor>
        <description>null</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
      </information>




      <resources>
            <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="Science_City.jar" download="eager" />
      </resources>

  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="java_video_in_browser.VideoPlayer"  name="VideoPlayer" >



     <fx:param name="video" value="Science_City_1"/>   
        </jfx:javafx-desc>  

    </jnlp>


This works if above changes are made in .jnlp file. The parameter value can be accessed from javafx application. I used following tag:  <jfx:javafx-desc to make it work. Also still the passing of parameters from jsp to javafx application via .jnlp does not work.
```

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully able to call Web Start Launcher from html link. The architechture here is html to Servlet, Servlet creates ,jnlp file dynamically with appropriate parameters and then the web start javafx application gets launched. The servlet uses file creation api and org.w3c.dom.Document api to place parameter values in xml .jnlp file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>


<FORM method="post" ACTION="http://localhost/science_city_video_1/Jnlp_Servlet" name="search_push">
            <input type="hidden" name="value" value="Science_City_Video_1"> 

<input type="hidden" name="video_description1" value="This is the First Video of Science City Cross Roads">  
<input type="hidden" name="jnlp_file_name" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="year" value="2017">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Ahmedabad">

                   <A href="javascript:document.search_push.submit()" class="style18"  >
                    This is our First Video of Science City Cross Roads

                    </A>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>



This is the html form that calls the servlet. 

The servlet code is as follows:

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.text.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;




/** needed in processing multipart web-form (especially to upload images) */
//import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.*;
import java.io.*;



/**
 * CLASS PhotoInsertionServlet DOES VERIFICATION OF INPUT FIELDS OF 
 * WEB-FORM AND THEN IT INSERTS DATA IN DATABASE.
 *
 * @version     1.00    28 August 2008
 * @author      Pushpendra Raval
 *
 */


public class Jnlp_Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** LOGGER IS USED TO LOG EXCEPTION MESSAGES.
     *  DETAILS OF LOG4J.XML IS EXPLAINED IN DOCS/CONFIGURATION FILES/LOG4J.TXT.
     */
/// Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PhotoInsertionServlet.class);

    /**
     * USED TO PRINT OUTPUT IN THANKYOUPAGE() METHOD 
     */


/** 
 * Method FUNCTION THIS METHOD IS OVERRIDDEN FROM HTTPSERLVET.JAVA CLASS.
 *                          
 * @param request   THIS IS HTTPSERVLETREQUEST PARAMETER OBTAINED BY 
 *          EXECUTING FORM. IN THIS CASE FORM IS PRESENT IN SUBMIT_REQUEST_APTSALE.HTML
 *
 * @param response  THIS IS HTTPSERVLETRESPSONSE PARAMETER WHICH OUTPUTS
 *                      NECESSARY HTML CODE TO THE VIEWER AFTER EXECUTING NECESSARY
 *                      CODE.
 *
 * @exception       IOException
 *          THIS EXCEPTION IS THROWN WHEN THERE IS INPUT-OUTPUT OPERATION ERROR
 *   
 *          SERVLETEXCEPTION
 *                      THIS EXCEPTION IS THROWN WHEN THERE IS ERROR IN SERVLET
 */

    PrintWriter out;


String jnlp_file_name = null;
String jnlp_file_name1 = null;
String parameter_Value = null;
String year = null;
String city = null;


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{

 response.setContentType("text/html");
 out = response.getWriter();  
 doPost(request, response);  

}

private void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}




public void jnlpParser(String filepath1, String parameter_Value, String filepath2, String city, String year) {

       try {
               System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 1");
        String filepath_u = filepath1+".jnlp";
                System.out.println("path:"+filepath_u);
               System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 2");
                File f = new File(filepath_u);
                System.out.println("FILE IS NULL OR NOT:"+f);
                System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 3");
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 4");
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(f);
                System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 5");


                Node root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            //    String url_value = "http://localhost/science_city_video_1/"+filepath2;
                ((Element)root).setAttribute("href",filepath2+".jnlp");
                 ((Element)root).setAttribute("codebase","http://localhost/videos/"+year+"/"+city+"/");
                System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 6");

        // Get the root element
        Node company = doc.getFirstChild();
 System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 7");
        // Get the staff element , it may not working if tag has spaces, or
        // whatever weird characters in front...it's better to use
        // getElementsByTagName() to get it directly.
        // Node staff = company.getFirstChild();

        // Get the staff element by tag name directly

                //NamedNodeMap attr = company.getAttributes();
        //Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("href");
        //nodeAttr.setTextContent("Science_City.jnlp");

                NodeList jnlpj = company.getChildNodes();
             System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 8");
//                NodeList list = staff.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < jnlpj.getLength(); i++) {
 System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 9");
                   Node node = jnlpj.item(i);



//      Element eElement = (Element) node;
//System.out.println(eElement);
           // get the salary element, and update the value
           if ("jfx:javafx-desc".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                   System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 10");     
             Element eElement = (Element) node;
            Element cElement =  (Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName("fx:param").item(0);
              System.out.println("inside jnlp parser 11");                 
           //String no = cElement.getAttribute("value");
             cElement.setAttribute("value", parameter_Value);

                       System.out.println("PUshpendras");
            //cElement.setTextContent("999");
           }



        }


        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath_u));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Done");

       } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{

 response.setContentType("text/html");
 out = response.getWriter();      

year = request.getParameter("year");
city = request.getParameter("city");
jnlp_file_name = request.getParameter("jnlp_file_name");
jnlp_file_name1 = "C://home/ahmedabadsale/videos/"+year+"/"+city+"/"+jnlp_file_name;
parameter_Value = request.getParameter("value");

System.out.println("JNLP FILE NAME:"+jnlp_file_name);
System.out.println("JNLP FILE NAME1:"+jnlp_file_name1);
System.out.println("Parameter Value:"+parameter_Value);



 try {
         File file = new File("C://home/ahmedabadsale/videos/"+year+"/"+city+"/"+jnlp_file_name+".jnlp");
         /*If file gets created then the createNewFile() 
          * method would return true or if the file is 
          * already present it would return false
          */
             System.out.println("1");
             boolean fvar = file.createNewFile();
         System.out.println("2");
             if (fvar){
                 System.out.println("3");
                 copyFileUsingStream(new File("C://home/ahmedabadsale/videos/Science_City.jnlp"), new File("C://home/ahmedabadsale/videos/"+year+"/"+city+"/"+jnlp_file_name+".jnlp")); 
                jnlpParser(jnlp_file_name1, parameter_Value, jnlp_file_name, city, year);
              System.out.println("File has been created successfully");
         }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
            e.printStackTrace();
      }



// PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.println("<html>");
 out.println("<head>");
 out.println("<title>");
 out.println("Web Start Application");
 out.println("</title>");
 out.println("</head>");
 out.println("<body>");
 out.println("<a href=http://localhost/videos/"+year+"/"+city+"/"+jnlp_file_name+".jnlp"+">Launch the Webstart Application"+"</a>");
 out.println("</body>");
 out.println("</html>");




System.out.println("4");


}

}


The .jnlp file which gets updated by Servlet is as follows:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
    <title>Science City Video</title>
    <vendor>Jahnvi Consultants</vendor>
    <description>null</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>




  <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="http://localhost/science_city_video_1/Science_City.jar" download="eager" />
  </resources>






  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="java_video_in_browser.VideoPlayer"  name="VideoPlayer" >

     <fx:param name="video" value=""/> 
 </jfx:javafx-desc>  
</jnlp>
```